# Is reading blocks of data from serial faster than reading 1 character at a time?

Tags: c, serial-port

Is it any faster to read large blocks from a serial port than to read 1 byte at a time? It is general knowledge that reading blocks is usually faster. But, I am wondering if this is the case with serial communication because:

1. Modern processor speeds with older protocols
2. Serial transmits 1 bit at a time, unlike new communication methods like USB

As a follow up, how does using a USB as a serial connection (using something like the PL2303 driver, if that helps) affect this?

This came up when I was thinking about how to parse incoming messages from a serial port. With the current design, it would be easier to parse the data 1 character at a time, but, I also want to do the reads efficiently.

Comment: Userland application? Or kernel driver?

Comment: Then try reading blocks. One system call per byte can be quite a lot of overhead.

Comment: "*Serial transmits 1 bit at a time, unlike new communication methods like USB"* -- USB is also serial, and transfer one bit at a time.  And by "serial", do you really mean EIA/RS-232 interfaces?

Comment: Is there an event that indicates new data is available?  If so read all available bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're hitting the serial hardware directly I would imagine that your OS will buffer incoming data and it will still be more efficient to read blocks of data at a time.

You could do it both ways and see which is faster though.

Also surely USB is a just a fast serial connection given the S stands for serial.